# Stop opening TFS builds in browser instead of IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I recently upgraded my team's build server to TFS2015 from TFS2013. Everything is going smoothly, except from within my IDE, I can no longer open the [Build Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181732.aspx). As far as I know, I have not changed any settings within my IDE, but builds now open as if I had selected the right-click context menu for [Open in Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181721.aspx#Instances) available for completed builds. This behavior started after I finished the TFS upgrade. As far as I know, I am the only one affected on my team.

Does anyone know how to convince Visual Studio 2015 to use the Build Explorer window again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build explorer is now available again in [Visual Studio 2015 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx) (for XAML builds)

Comment: I just confirmed this. My team has already moved on past XAML Builds, so too late for me. Thanks for the head's up!

Answer (score 5):

No, if you use VS2015 to connect to TFS2015, the Build Explorer is no longer exists, you need to view builds on the build page.

However, if you use VS2013 to connect to TFS2015, or use VS2015 to connect to TFS2013, the Build Explorer is still available in VS IDE.

Comment: Do you know if there is any plan to show the timestamps of the individual build steps in the web based build progress screen? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35696832/tfs-2015-xaml-build-progress-inside-visual-studio-2015?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm running TFS2015 update 4 and VS2015 and this interface is really inconsistent for me. Half the time the builds open in VS and the other half the browser window opens.