# TFS 2015 - XAML build progress inside Visual Studio 2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

We've recently upgraded to TFS 2015 - everything is working well although I've noticed that when we queue one of our XAML builds from Visual Studio and then double click the build to check its progress, it opens into the Team Foundation web UI (in a browser) where as it used to open a status window within Visual Studio itself.

The web based build progress screen is missing some key information for us - the time taken for each step of the build (we have a part of the build that does a a Thread.Sleep whilst some servers are drained and there is now no way to see how far through that step we are as the timestamps are not outputted on the web build status page).

Is there a way to a) open the build summary in Visual Studio like TFS 2013 did? or b) get TFS to show the timestamps against each individual step of the build in the web UI status page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build explorer is now available again in [Visual Studio 2015 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx) (for XAML builds)

Answer (score 2):

1. see [Stop opening TFS builds in browser instead of IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483896/stop-opening-tfs-builds-in-browser-instead-of-ide)
2. I'm using the [Build Explorer](https://buildexplorer.codeplex.com/) tool from codeplex in order to get all the build details.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't see this post before.